# DataTable Expression returns "Infinity" and "Nan" on DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataTable` of data retrieved from a database, and the last column calculated like this:

```
dt.Columns.Add("PERCENTAGE", typeof(float));
dt.Columns["PERCENTAGE"].Expression = "(total *100)/budget";
```

Then I bind it to a `DataGridView`.

My problem is that sometimes the "budget" column has a value of 0, so I get either "Infinity" or "NaN" displayed in the DataGridView cell. I'd like to simply display a "-" in this cases.

I've tried doing it on `CellFormatting` but I get an error since Expression columns are Read-Only.

Is there a way to get the result I want?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the Expression syntax.  You can use IIF for a conditional expression and CONVERT to convert to a string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks, I looked into it and managed to almost get the result I wanted using this code. `dt.Columns["PERCENTAGE"].Expression = "IIF([budget] = 0, '-', total*100/budget)"` but I get a lot of decimals, I tried using `SUBSTRING`  on the _falsepart_ of the IIF but I couldn't get it to work, any ideas?

Comment: For anyone interested I managed to get it working using this code: `dt.Columns["PERCENTAGE"].Expression = "IIF([budget] = 0, '-', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(total*100/budget, System.String), 1, 5) + '%')";`